# Unable to run older version of MongoDB with native commands

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I inadvertently updated my MongoDB from 3.6 to 4.0 via Homebrew and I specifically need 3.6. I manually uninstalled 4.0 and installed `mongodb@3.6`, but now, I'm having issues starting the shell and running MongoDB. Here are my logs from when I run `mongod`:

```
2019-08-06T20:28:31.789-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=19110 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Mac.local
2019-08-06T20:28:31.790-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.8
2019-08-06T20:28:31.790-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6bc9ed599c3fa164703346a22bad17e33fa913e4
2019-08-06T20:28:31.790-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2s  28 May 2019
2019-08-06T20:28:31.790-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2019-08-06T20:28:31.790-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-08-06T20:28:31.790-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-08-06T20:28:31.790-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-08-06T20:28:31.790-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-08-06T20:28:31.790-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-08-06T20:28:31.791-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2019-08-06T20:28:31.791-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7680M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),cache_cursors=false,compatibility=(release="3.0",require_max="3.0"),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-08-06T20:28:32.496-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1565137712:496925][19110:0x1061935c0], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 151/768
2019-08-06T20:28:32.582-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1565137712:582290][19110:0x1061935c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 151 through 152
2019-08-06T20:28:32.651-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1565137712:651239][19110:0x1061935c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 152 through 152
2019-08-06T20:28:32.702-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1565137712:702411][19110:0x1061935c0], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-08-06T20:28:32.902-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2019-08-06T20:28:33.010-0400 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.
2019-08-06T20:28:33.010-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-08-06T20:28:33.010-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-08-06T20:28:33.010-0400 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutdown: removing all drop-pending collections...
2019-08-06T20:28:33.012-0400 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutdown: removing checkpointTimestamp collection...
2019-08-06T20:28:33.013-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2019-08-06T20:28:33.321-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1565137713:321125][19110:0x1061935c0], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 152/4480
2019-08-06T20:28:33.417-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1565137713:417952][19110:0x1061935c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 152 through 153
2019-08-06T20:28:33.491-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1565137713:491659][19110:0x1061935c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 153 through 153
2019-08-06T20:28:33.542-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1565137713:542091][19110:0x1061935c0], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019-08-06T20:28:33.733-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2019-08-06T20:28:33.736-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-08-06T20:28:33.736-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:62
```

I'm a front-end dev, so not a MongoDB expert, but it seems as though the `mongod` and `mongo` commands are no longer linked properly and I have to manually run `brew services start mongodb@3.6` or `/usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.6/bin/mongod` to start the service. After running either of these, I can successfully run the Mongo shell.

Also, my `~/.zsh` file has `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.6/bin:$PATH"` at the very bottom.

My questions are:

1. How do I fix the upgrade problem mentioned in the logs?
2. How do I re-link the `mongod` and `mongo` commands?
3. Should I clean up any leftover files from all these installs?

Comment: where did you originally install mongo from? and did you take a backup of your data files? if it was installed from rpm and your data files are safe you should be able to downgrade.

Comment: @user3788685 I originally installed `mongodb` from Homebrew and then updated my packages. I didn't take a backup, but I'm not worried about my database as I can restore it. I'm more concerned with the MongoDB installation

Comment: are you happy to install from rpm ? it's easier and easier to maintain - if yes i'll sort you out some details later this evening GMT

Comment: @user3788685 I'm not familiar with rpm. I think if I could just get the commands working again, the 3.6 installation would be fine

Comment: I can't personally help with home-brew/source builds but can with pre-built rpm's long as your data is safe I suggest you just install from rpm unless you have some specific needs